# Why isn't webpack-dev-server proxying API calls in React application? Returning 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, webpack-dev-server

I'm building a fullstack React application with a Postgres database connected by Express/Node. I'm not using create-react-app. To test API calls, I'm calling the API in `componentDidMount()` with axios. The server is running on port `3000` and the react application is running on port `8080`. I've tested the `/users` endpoint in Postman to ensure it works.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // failing config for webpack dev server:
  axios.get('/api/users')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.response)
  })
  // fails:
  // axios.get('/users')
  // .then((response) => {
  //   console.log(response)
  // })
  // .catch((err) => {
  //   console.log(err);
  //   console.log(err.response)
  // })

  // works fine:
  // axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
  // .then((response) => {
  //   console.log(response)
  // })
  // .catch((err) => {
  //   console.log(err)
  // })
}
```

Note that calling `localhost:3000` directly works, but I want to be able to call `/users` to prepare for a production environment. So I added the following in my webpack.config.js file:

```
  devServer: {
 contentBase: __dirname,
 hot: true,
 historyApiFallback: true,
 open: true,
 proxy: {
  '/api': 'http://localhost:3000',
  changeOrigin: true
  }
}
```

Is there something else I need to add for proxying API calls when running webpack-dev-server? From the tutorials I've seen, having the proxy configuration in `webpack.config.js` is sufficient, but I'm only getting 404s.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the leading / in your get request.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, at least for me, ended up being using react environment variables that will dynamically determine the url to point to. I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5. Just point your dev env to localhost and then whatever port your server is on.